# SQL divide and group by id

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have the following query below. I'm trying to pull a count of records with specific criteria then divide by the total number of records grouped by cstmr_id. However I'm getting an error. Any help would be appreciated. Also, this statement is a subquery and part of a larger select query. I'm using SQL Server 2005

Getting a "Incorrect syntax near '/'" error

Statement:

```
((SELECT count(*) FROM cstmr WHERE active=1 AND cstmr_type LIKE '%dtr%' 
GROUP BY cstmr_id) 
/  --division sign here. dividing top query by bottom
(SELECT count(*) FROM cstmr WHERE cstmr_type LIKE '%dtr%'
GROUP BY cstmr_id) ) As cstmr_rate
```

Sample Data In cstmr table:

```
cstmr_id    cstmr_type    active
3423        dtr           1
1236        dtr           1
1842        dtr           1
8273        sys           2
9384        aod           1
3847        sys           2
```

Sample Expected Result:

```
cstmr_id    cstmr_rate
3423        88.98
1236        25.21
1842        58.01
```

Basic Pseudocode

Select only active customers that are of type "dtr" and then divide by the total number of customers. Then display this derived ratio for each individual customer. This is a very basic equation and uses the same table "cstr"

Comment: The actually error and the full sql statement would most likely help

Comment: Well, I'm getting a "Incorrect syntax near '/' "

Comment: Can you show the whole query so people can figure out what the problem is? My guess is you have an opening parenthesis earlier in the code that is causing the issue here.

Comment: Also why do you have `group by` in there? If `cstmr_id` is unique, `COUNT(*)` will always be 1.

Comment: Actually if I try to execute this statement alone I get that :-( Firstly I'm trying to make it work standalone from the rest of the query.

Comment: @dido if you execute it alone, do you have the opening `select` as pointed out in my answer.  if not, then you will get the same error.

Comment: You can't execute only this piece of code. Have you tried what bluefeet recommended?

Comment: Yes I did try it. But all I get is just one zero

Comment: @dido you are getting zero because the returned value of count is an `int` you will need to `cast()` it, see my answer

Comment: Oh, right I didn't see that..let me try it.

Comment: Why do you dislike vowels? Is `cstmr` really that much faster to type than a word like `customer`?

Comment: I modified the query names/variables. The information is sensitive so I do not want to disclose the actual names in the database nor any data...

Comment: Please see my modified post. I posted the pseudocode on the end of my post. I think it helps to explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @dido please post some sample data.  the expected result is great but the sample data prior to the result would be much better

Comment: Active is 1 or 2 instead of 1 or 0?

Comment: yes,correct active is 1.

Comment: Why isn't inactive = 0 instead of 2?

Comment: Sorry, mistake. It's a 0. Don't know why I put 2 there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely not working because those two queries are returning more than one record.  SQL Server can't divide a result set by a result set.

Try using joins to pull those counts instead.

EDIT

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    c.cstmr_id,
    c1/c2 AS 'cstmr_rate'
FROM cstmr as c
JOIN (
    SELECT cstmr_id, count(*) AS 'c1'
    FROM cstmr 
    WHERE active=1 
    AND cstmr_type LIKE '%dtr%' 
    GROUP BY cstmr_id
    ) AS sub1 ON c.cstmr_id = sub1.cstmr_id
JOIN (
    SELECT cstmr_id, count(*) AS 'c2'
    FROM cstmr 
    WHERE cstmr_type LIKE '%dtr%'
    GROUP BY cstmr_id
    ) AS sub2 ON c.cstmr_id = sub2.cstmr_id
```

EDIT2

This would probably work too, assuming that active is either a 1 or 0:

```
SELECT
    cstmr_id,
    SUM(Active)/COUNT(*)  AS 'cstmr_rate'
FROM cstmr
GROUP BY cstmr_id
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your first solution, but I'm getting an error message saying "Invalid column name 'cstmr_id'" on the first GROUP BY

Comment: If it's a bit, your second query returns an error, probably need to convert. Also it's still doing integer math.

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT cstmr_id, active, c = COUNT(*) 
   FROM dbo.cstmr WHERE cstmr_type LIKE '%dtr%'
   GROUP BY cstmr_id, active
), 
cr(cstmr_id, cstmr_rate) AS
(
  SELECT cstmr_id, 
   SUM(CASE active WHEN 1 THEN c ELSE 0 END)*1.0 / SUM(c) 
  FROM x GROUP BY cstmr_id
)
SELECT cr.cstmr_id, cr.cstmr_rate --, other columns
FROM cr
--INNER JOIN -- other tables from your larger query
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing an outer `SELECT`:

```
select -- You are missing this
(
    (SELECT cast(count(*) as decimal(10,2))
    FROM cstmr 
    WHERE active=1 AND cstmr_type LIKE '%dtr%' 
    GROUP BY cstmr_id) 
/  --division sign here. dividing top query by bottom
    (SELECT cast(count(*) as decimal(10,2))
    FROM cstmr 
    WHERE cstmr_type LIKE '%dtr%'
    GROUP BY cstmr_id) 
) As cstmr_rate
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but the question makes it clear that this is a subquery.  I imagine that is the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @GordonLinoff well without seeing the entire query it is difficult, but I just ran a similar query on sql-server 2005 and it worked without any issues

Comment: @dido please see my edit, trying a `cast()` around the `count()` since it returns an `int`

Comment: Well I tried it but it returns error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, >

Comment: @dido that's because you have a `GROUP BY` in there for some reason, as I mentioned in my comment above. Remove the two `GROUP BY` lines and try again.

Comment: Well if I remove it then it gives me a single number..however I want this for every individual id...not just an aggregate. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @dido can you post a sample of data from the table as well as the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from your syntax problems, there are much easier ways to express what you want:

```
select count(distinct case when active = 1 then cstmr_id end)*1.0 / count(distinct cstmr_id)
from cstmr
where cstmr_type like '%dtr%'
```

If cstmr_id is not repeated in the cstmr table, you can further simplify this as:

```
select sum(case when active = 1 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / count(*)
from cstmr
where cstmr_type like '%dtr%'
```

Or even:

```
select avg(active*1.0)
from cstmr
where cstmr_type like '%dtr%'
```

Note that I've also converted the integers to floating point.  As you've written it, the values it produces are either 0 or 1, because SQL Server does integer arithmetic on integers.